# How to cut a file from my USB drive and paste it elsewhere in Finder on Mac OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, finder, copy-paste

When I click <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> to try and cut the file on my USB drive so I can paste it elsewhere and free up space on my USB, it does nothing, and when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click it only gives the option to copy the file, not cut it.

How to **cut**-and-paste a file on OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy, then <kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste in a new location and delete from the original location.

Comment: Option-command-V was added in 10.7, so it doesn't work in 10.6.8 though.

Comment: Only user57827 knows what version was intended by "OS X" in the question.